# K3S on Raspberry Pi 4 - kubectl get pods runs into timeout

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, kubernetes-helm, k3s

### Problem

When I connect a k3s agent to the server and run "kubectl get nodes" on the server. I get the following error:

```
root@k3s-master:/home/marc# kubectl get nodes
Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get nodes)
```

But if the server is standalone, I can easily run "kubectl get nodes".

CPU utilisation on the server stays about 30-40%. And RAM usage is at 583M of 3.74G.

### Specs

- 2x Raspberry Pi 4b with 4GB RAM
- Fresh install of raspbian lite (buster)
- Enabled legacy iptables and cgroups

### K3S Installation

On the server, I've done:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
```

And on the agent:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL=https://k3s-master:6443 K3S_TOKEN=<token> sh -
```

Thanks in advance, it drives me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to stack overflows related question feature, I've stumbled upon this question: [PI4 k3s install server currently unable to handle the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132229/pi4-k3s-install-server-currently-unable-to-handle-the-request?rq=1)

There seems to be an issue regarding cgroup memory failures with buster kernel 5.4.x

#### Edit

Adding the cgroup didnt helped, so I switched to Ubuntu 20.05 and its working now.